# Spring MVC on GAE: 500 Internal Server Error (Intellij)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I'm getting these errors after putting on code for Spring MVC. It's a maven project with Google App Engine running on Intellij IDEA. Before I started using Spring MVC framework and adding in the .xml files for spring-servlet, everything was running fine. Can anyone help me to figure out what this error means and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

```
bad runtime process port ['']

at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:268)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:284)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.devappserver2.DevAppServer2Impl.doStart(DevAppServer2Impl.java:250)
at ...

    Feb 10, 2017 9:26:25 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.devappserver2.RemoteApiDelegate log
SEVERE: [1486761985829000] javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:79)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
...

Feb 10, 2017 9:26:25 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed spring-web: java.lang.NullPointerException
Feb 10, 2017 9:26:25 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Failed startup of context com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@fdefd3f{/,D:\CSE308Project\teambuildingexercise\todolist\target\todolist-1.0-SNAPSHOT}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:256)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
...

Feb 10, 2017 9:26:25 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@localhost:54107
Feb 10, 2017 9:26:25 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:54107/
Feb 10, 2017 9:26:25 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:54107/_ah/admin
Feb 10, 2017 4:26:25 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.devappserver2.DevAppServer2Impl doStart
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
```

If anymore parts of my project is needed, please let me know and i'll post more.
(Already running on jdk1.7, still get the same error.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. It was a dependency problem.
Make sure add the correct dependency in pom.xml.

```
<!-- Spring MVC Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```